# Repair Broken Nested Set

Tags: php, mysql

I have to repair broken nested set chains via script or sql. The table contains a left and a right value column, but no parent id column.
I am able to compute the level of each node within the nested set. There are gaps in left and right values. The structure of computed levels is valid.
Does someone know a solution to close the gaps via SQL? (MySQL)

None of the suggestions fit to my problem, but thanks for your engagement.

I worked out a solution for me:
 1. first step compute parent ids and transform to adjacency list
 2. use Joe Celko's approach to convert adjacency lists to nested sets
 3. update old left and right values

Comment: So you want to store the parent id like in an adjacency list ( additionally to left/right)?

Answer (score 1):

i would just generate a parent_id column from the left and right values you have, then regenerate the left and right values.

if you don't want to modify your current table, you could even do this in a temporary table.

Comment: I have to agree - you are quite screwed without parent_id. Or at least that is what I found out after dealing with the same problem.

Comment: I solved the problem to compute the parent_id (without having a parent column) by using a following SQL:

SELECT A.id, IF(B.id IS NULL, 1, B.id) AS parent FROM page AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN page AS B ON B.tree_lft = (SELECT MAX(C.tree_lft) FROM page AS C WHERE A.tree_lft > C.tree_lft AND A.tree_lft < C.tree_rgt);

Answer (score 1):

Each ancestor of a node (c) has a smaller `left` and bigger `right` value. And the immediate parent (p) is the one in that set (of ancestors) with the biggest `left` value.

E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE nested (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(16),
  parentid int DEFAULT 0,
  lft int(11),
  rgt int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO
    nested (name, parentid, lft, rgt)
VALUES
    ('1'      ,0,1,20),
    ('1.1'    ,0,2,9),
    ('1.1.1'  ,0,3,4),
    ('1.1.2'  ,0,5,6),
    ('1.1.3'  ,0,7,8),
    ('1.2'    ,0,10,19),
    ('1.2.1'  ,0,11,14),
    ('1.2.1.1',0,12,13),
    ('1.2.2'  ,0,15,16),
    ('1.2.3'  ,0,17,18)

SELECT
  p.id as pid, p.name as pname,
  c.id as cid, c.name as cname  
FROM
  nested as c
LEFT JOIN
  nested as p
ON
  p.lft=(
    SELECT
      MAX(lft)
    FROM
      nested AS l
    WHERE
      c.lft > l.lft
      AND c.lft < l.rgt
  )
```

returns

```
pid    pname    cid    cname
NULL   NULL     1      1
1      1        2      1.1
2      1.1      3      1.1.1
2      1.1      4      1.1.2
2      1.1      5      1.1.3
1      1        6      1.2
6      1.2      7      1.2.1
7      1.2.1    8      1.2.1.1
6      1.2      9      1.2.2
6      1.2      10     1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 or 5 different cases for corruption in a nested set that are completely fixable (if done in the right order). Snaggle is easy to prevent with a simple trigger the checks to see if the Left is not >= the Right. I have gotten the best results from repairing a nested set in this order. The SQL itself is not difficult once the problem is broken down as follows.

- Cross (1:4 3:6) or (1:2 2:3)
- Under/Over (1:4 1:3) OR (1:4 2:4)
- Gap (2:3 5:6 1:7) or (2:4 5:6 1:7)
- Snaggle (2:1 4:2) OR (1:1)